# Xpath expression for council website

Tags: php, xpath

From this URL:

https://www.walsall.gov.uk/Waste/bincollections/Details/100071042591

I want to extract the indivual bin dates from the webpage.

When I inpsect with Chrome, and copy xpath for the first bin date, I get the following XPath:

```
//*[@id="main"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

Which looks good, but I get a length of zero from my $xpath->query object.

However, when I put my query as:

```
//*[@id="main"]/h3[2]
```

I get the right value (Green Bin, Recycling).

Can anyone tell me why the first XPath query isnt working? It looks perfectly logical to me.

Comment: First `XPath` returns `22/03/2017` while `//*[@id="main"]/h3[2]` returns `Green Bin (Recycling)`. There are different target tags in your expressions so different results is normal... Can you clarify what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry the problem was that the first XPath wasn't returning any data.  I have since found that it was because of the tbody tag inserted by Chrome that was the issue.  The h3[2] was simply a test to make sure I was receiving data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `<tbody>` tag, I took that out and ended with this:

```
//*[@id="main"]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[2]
```

My guess is when I inspected Chrome inserted the tbody tag when you inspect, but it is not actually present in the raw HTML served by the server.

Comment: this does not actually return anything from the page... try this out: open chrome, go to page, f12 to bring up dev tools, console tab, type in `$x("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tr[2]/td[2]")` and enter, no results right? but if you try `$x("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")`, it returns `22/03/2017` as Andersson mentioned. You probably just inspected the wrong element.

Comment: @becixb Okay, because the chrome inspector is *adding in* the tbody it works, but in the actual raw source of the page the tbody is not present so when you run the xpath query with php you get the right result.